# For Android and iOS, can I distribute a basic version of my app, and then distribute extensions to it?

Tags: android, ios, app-store

If I build an app for iOS and Android and I distribute it. Let's call this the basic version of my app. A year later, if I decide on a change to my app (a new view or feature) but I only want to distribute this to some users, can I list it as a separate app on the app stores as a "extension"? Then when downloaded (by someone who already has the basic app) it simply extends the functionality. If it's downloaded by someone who doesn't have the basic app, it prompts them to download the basic app along with it?

Comment: If I download an app and it tells me I first need to go download another. I will immediately delete that app. An app should be a full app, not part of a jigsaw, where I have to download each piece

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Yeah, I share that same concern, but I'm torn, because if I have a basic app, those users are fine, great, but then for users who need a whole bunch of additional functionality, if I create a separate app, then what do they do with the old one when they "upgrade"? And, do they need to transfer their data over to the new app? It becomes disjointed. If I offer only the more complicated app, I annoy my basic users. Make sense? I'm sure there's a good solution, that's why I'm here : ) Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I have literally never downloaded an app and said to myself, what would make this better is if they got rid of half of the features. I have thought the UI is too cluttered and messy, but not too many features. You need to make an update to the existing version and place the new features appropriately. Trying to manage X apps, asking users to download others, expecting users to find the right one etc. are all going to drive away a lot more users than "too many features"

Comment: Haha, too many features is a very common problem. From far better app developers than me: https://gettingreal.37signals.com/ (Read "Forget feature requests). Also, feel free to search "unbundling of apps". There are lots of organizations splitting up their apps (Dropbox, FB, Google, etc).

Comment: yes FB is splitting their apps and as an avid user I can contest to how ridiculously annoying it is that I can no longer access the messaging in app. They claim it was to speed up app loading times and I can assure you the length of time it takes to context switch the far outweighs any possible gains. These changes are amongst the top complaints of the app. Too many features are not an issue so long as the ui is designed appropriately. If the basic users never see them or have to filter through them, it will never bother them

Comment: if you choose to copy FB, thats your decision. But as an app developer and an app user I would implore you to not do it. Just because companies are doing it doesn't mean users like like

Comment: I see where you're coming from. The idea that features don't have to clutter the interface is useful. Perhaps they're even disabled by default, and enabling them is the "upgrade" or a "reward", as a form of gamification. Haha, "following facebook" definitely not my agenda : ) Thanks for sharing your thoughts, Simon. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can do this. Android platform offers `IPC` (Interprocess Communication) mechanism via [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) (in Android every app is run in its own process by default) and it will be probably used to communicate between your apps. To get information about other apps you can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).